# Sharing method implementation between two derived classes

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to share an implementation of a method between two derived classes:

```
class BaseClass() {
    abstract method1();
}

class OtherClass extends BaseClass() {
    method1() {...};
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass() {
    method1 = OtherClass.prototype.method1; // TSC error
}
```

but the indicated line gives the error

> Class 'BaseClass' defines instance member function 'method1', but extended class 'MyClass' defines it as an instance member property.

A kind of annoying workaround is to include a no-op implementation and reassign the method to the prototype:

```
class MyClass extends BaseClass () {
    method1() { /*noop*/ };
}
MyClass.prototype.method1 = OtherClass.prototype.method1;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to share methods, but you can write this to avoid having the no-op implementation:

```
class MyClass {
}
interface MyClass {
    method1(): void;
}
MyClass.prototype.method1 = OtherClass.prototype.method1;
```

Answer (score -1):

If both classes need to have the same implementation then they need to inherit a base class that holds that implementation, that's how it's treated in OO.

If you don't want to have `method1` in `BaseClass` because you have a fourth class that needs to inherit `BaseClass` and needs to have a different implementation of `method` than the other two classes the you need another level of inheritance:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    abstract method1();
}

class A {
    method1() { console.log("A"); }
}

class AnotherBase extends BaseClass {
    method1() { console.log("AnotherBase"); }
}

class B extends AnotherBase {}

class C extends AnotherBase {}
```

Now `B` and `C` share the implementation of `method1` using `AnotherBase` but `A` has it's own implementation.

Let's say that later in the future you'll want `MyClass.method1` to do something before/after the execution of `OtherClass.method1`?
In your implementation of `MyClass.method1` you won't be as easy/pretty to call the `OtherClass.method1` as it is in my example.

```
MyClass.prototype.method1 = function() {
    console.log("MyClass");
    OtherClass.prototype.method1();
}
```

VS

```
class B extends AnotherBase {
    method1() {
        console.log("B");
        super.method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: "If both classes need to have the same implementation then they need to inherit a base class that holds that implementation" -- totally false; this is how you end up in the BaseBean anti-pattern. Doubly so in a language like TS that lacks multiple inheritance -- how do you share one method between B and C and another between C and D? Class heritage should represent hierarchies of substitutable components, not similarity of behavior.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I disagree with your disagreement: 1. same implementation is different than same functionality (classes vs interfaces), 2. Typescript does have multiple inheritance using mixins. In this example doing `MyClass.prototype.method1 = OtherClass.prototype.method1` will screw things up if `OtherClass.method1` will call `this.doSometihng` and both classes have this method implemented.